# How to fix Spinner not properly showing selected item after OnItemSelected call in fragment?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am creating a SportsApp and in my NFL page where the user would select the Week they want to view, it does not show the week the user selected but the proper data displays. The spinner displays the default Week 1 text but loads the correct value for the selected week.

```
 public class NFLWeekSpinner extends Fragment {

    Spinner NFLspinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter;
    String inputWeekFormatted;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nfl_spinner_frag,container,false);
        NFLspinner = view.findViewById(R.id.NFLSpinner);

        spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getActivity(),R.array.weekNum,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        //spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        NFLspinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

        NFLspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            boolean user = false;

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if(user) {
                    String selectedWeek = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    if (selectedWeek.length() > 6) {
                        inputWeekFormatted = selectedWeek.substring(5, 7);
                    } else {
                        inputWeekFormatted = selectedWeek.substring(5, 6);

                    }
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).loadNFLscoreboard(inputWeekFormatted);
                }
                user = true;

                // count++;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }

        });



        return view;

    }
 @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String BACK_ROOT_STACK = "root_fragment";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

        //loadMLBScoreboard(defaultDate);
        loadNavBar();
    }
    public void loadNavBar() {

        final BottomNavigationView mBottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        final String defaultDate = "20180915";
        mBottomNav.setItemIconTintList(null);
        mBottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                mBottomNav.setItemIconTintList(null);

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.menu_nfl:
                        loadNFLscoreboard("1");
                        break;
                    case R.id.menu_baseball:
                        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");


                        String today = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                        loadMLBScoreboard(defaultDate);
                        break;

                        default:

                            loadMLBScoreboard(defaultDate);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadMLBScoreboard(String inputDate) {

        LoadScoreboardFragment loadScoreboardFragment = new LoadScoreboardFragment();

        loadMLBFragment(inputDate, loadScoreboardFragment);
    }

    private void loadMLBFragment(String inputDate, LoadScoreboardFragment loadScoreboardFragment) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        //Load date Fragment
        DateFragment dateFragment = new DateFragment();

        bundle.putString("inputDateKey", inputDate);
        loadScoreboardFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction newFT = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        newFT.add(loadScoreboardFragment, "Loading");
        newFT.replace(R.id.holderFragment, dateFragment)
                .addToBackStack(BACK_ROOT_STACK)
                .commit();
    }
    public void loadNFLscoreboard(String nflWeek) {
        LoadNFLscoreboardFragment loadNFLscoreboardFragment = new LoadNFLscoreboardFragment();
        NFLWeekSpinner weekSpinner = new NFLWeekSpinner();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString("inputWeekKey",nflWeek);
        loadNFLscoreboardFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_recycle, loadNFLscoreboardFragment)
                .commit();

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.holderFragment,weekSpinner)
                    .addToBackStack(BACK_ROOT_STACK)
                    .commit();
      }
    }
```

**R.array.WeekNum**

```
 <string-array name="weekNum">
    <item>Week 1</item>
    <item>Week 2</item>
    <item>Week 3</item>
    <item>Week 4</item>
    <item>Week 5</item>
    <item>Week 6</item>
    <item>Week 7</item>
    <item>Week 8</item>
    <item>Week 9</item>
    <item>Week 10</item>
    <item>Week 11</item>
    <item>Week 12</item>
    <item>Week 13</item>
    <item>Week 14</item>
    <item>Week 15</item>
    <item>Week 16</item>
    <item>Week 17</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Please post `R.array.weekNum`. BTW, using the display value to get the selected week, is bad designing. What will happen when you add a Spanish translation?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I posted R.arrary.weekNum. As far as the selected week, correct me if I'm wrong but i thought since i am getting the item at position of the selected week, i would have circumvented this.

Comment: No, what would happen when you show in Spanish "Semana 1", then your code `selectedWeek.substring(5, 7)` will fail. You can get around it, but the correct way would be to have a separate array with the values. But in your case, no need for anything, just `week=position+1;`. As for your issue, the code looks fine, maybe you are overriding a different function in the class. Did you post the full `NFLWeekSpinner` class?

Comment: Ah okay i see what you mean, thank you again. I added the only thing missing from NFLWeekSpinner class. i also added my main activity in case that helps. What's odd is that when i click the back button i briefly see the spinner change to the selectedWeek but then goes back to Week 1 . Sort of like if i am defaulting it to Week 1 when the view gets created but i dont see any signs of that.

Comment: When do you have issue, when user sees it for first time, or even when user selects a different value from spinner?

Comment: So when the user first loads the NFL fragment it loads the default Week 1 value in the spinner and corresponding data. When the user selects a different week from the spinner, the value displayed in the spinner does not change but the corresponding data loads from the API call correctly.      So initially you'll have week 1 displayed in the spinner with week 1 games. then you change the week but you still have week 1 displayed in the spinner but with the games from the week you selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out!!! In the `NFLSpinner.OnItemSelected` call, once the user selected the new week, i was making a call to the `MainActivity loadNFLScoreboard` method which was creating a new instance of the Spinner on each call. I moved the `NFLWeekSpinner` declaration to outside the `loadNFLScoreboad` method and since there wasn't a new spinner being created on each call, the selected week properly displayed.

Thanks for all your help @lionscribe